# ¿Como realizar operaciones con listas anidadas en python?

Tags: python, pandas

Me podrían ayudar con el siguiente problema: necesito realizar las siguientes operaciones

1.He agrupado estos datos de la siguiente manera: hay 5 valores en cada lista de Dist y 5 valores en cada lista de Estaciones

```
Dist=[[30370.795616367926,  33815.150693594594,46185.71842545861,  19320.833294896944, 15449.384875278663],
[55746.82398877258, 61806.105241266116,  67302.84069931255,  39495.05723890139,  13178.05975450182],
[56614.6453128695,  62824.890505167576,  68316.55751797787,  40262.03669361839,  14228.433386197994],
[61985.760770983725,  70712.38907644356,  78442.56823752768,  44610.89666988611,  23634.688882716953],
[36756.67910728118,  50115.13939244232,  68294.77551359401,  18924.159275056474,  22033.829359066545]]

 Estaciones=[[5.5, 5.0, 4.0, 23.6, 0.0],[1.2, 0.0, 2.4, 20.2, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 7.6, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.2, 6.8],[0.0, 18.0, 10.2, 17.2, 2.6],[0.0, 0.0, 3.1, 2.6, 3.2],[2.5, 51.8, 3.2, 16.4, 9.3],
[12.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0], [52.0, 0.0, 4.0, 44.4, 50.7]]
```

2.Estas son unas de las operaciones que tengo que realizar: Para cada lista de Dist debo recorrer todas las listas de estaciones realizando este calculo como los ejemplos mostrados (estos son para la primera lista Dist) de esta manera tengo que realizar mi calculo y finalmete crar una sola lista con todos los valores en orden

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente realize un calculo similar, pero esta vez la funcion que elaboré no cumple con lo que necesito y me da error:

```
def IDW(Estaciones, distancias):
    listaResultado = []
    e = Estaciones
    d = distancias
    for i in range(len(d[0])):
        sumaSuperior = 0
        sumaInferior = 0
        for j in range(len(e)):
             sumaSuperior += e[j]/(d[j][i] ** 2)
             sumaInferior += 1/(d[j][i] ** 2)
        listaResultado.append(sumaSuperior/sumaInferior)
    return listaResultado
IDW(Estaciones,Dist)
```

El resultado seria así :

```
   [8.1144, 6.08207,  2.20524,  0.045387, …. ]
```

Comment: Creo que deberias eliminar la etiqueta de `pandas`, pues no creo que esté relacionado con tu pregunta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explicación

Déjame proponerte otro enfoque, usando la funcion [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para emparejar las estaciones y las distancias. Esta funcion recibe `n` cantidad de iterables del mimso tamaño y retorna un arreglo de tuplas con el emparejamiento de cada iterable.

Entonces, vamos a obtener cada sublista de la lista de estaciones y distancias, y estas sublistas serán las que vamos a pasar por el metodo [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Es importante que notes que el `for` mas externo debe ser con la lista de distancias, y luego con la lista de estaciones. Esto es importante, pues cada distancia debe repetirse para todas las estaciones.

De esta forma, para la primera iteracion, la variable `distancia` será `[30370.795616367926,  33815.150693594594,46185.71842545861,  19320.833294896944, 15449.384875278663]` y no cambiará su valor hasta que hayamos recorrido todas las estaciones.

Por otro lado, vamos a tener dos arreglos llamados `numeradores` y `denominadores`, en estos vamos a ir guardando las operaciones de division que necesitas realizar, algo como:

```
numeradores = [5.5 / distancia1^2, 5.0 / distancia2^2, 4.0 / distancia3^2, 23.6 / distancia4^2, 0.0 / distancia5^2]

denominadores = [1 / distancia1^2, 1 / distancia2^2, 1 / distancia3^2, 1 / distancia4^2, 1 / distancia5^2]
```

Para posteriormente hacer una suma de todas esas divisiones almacenadas usando el método [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). Hasta este punto ya tendriamos tanto el numerador como el denominador completado.

Solo hace falta la division mas grande, la cual se hace con la sentencia: `resultado.append(numerador/denominador)`, donde la guardamos de una vez en la lista de resultados. Así lo hariamos por cada sublista de distancia, hasta terminar.

### Código

```
def IDW(estaciones, distancias):
  resultado = []
  for distancia in distancias:
    for estacion in estaciones:
      numeradores = []
      denominadores = []
      for e, d in zip(estacion, distancia):
        numeradores.append(e/d**2)
        denominadores.append(1/d**2)
      
      numerador = sum(numeradores)
      denominador = sum(denominadores)
      resultado.append(numerador/denominador)
      #resultado.sort() Descomentar si quieres obtener los resultados ordenados
  return resultado

print(IDW(Estaciones, Dist))
```

### Resultado

```
[8.114426157909593, 6.082077324886027, 2.2052439050816206, 8.309473993020557, 8.33615093042244, 2.347806678065492, 14.243615414850696, 6.842829433254822, 41.911346656631956, 2.6501940002596154, 1.9248120545695222, 0.6855408873809209, 7.055273143179902, 4.575698400618734, 2.8843140599616572, 10.98559191512143, 10.141657526932427, 46.923829803039034, 2.9037758102561035, 2.1069671664430283, 0.7500984269377915, 7.07322835278474, 4.766269696789622, 2.85267215258767, 11.149601124473701, 9.960781151973753, 46.54405308704843, 5.124426004556015, 3.7223942031768438, 1.3265886804572038, 7.312242777850483, 6.364255147990041, 2.585837620994242, 12.491978666657134, 8.466492513207887, 43.64917828258998, 11.735739636837028, 9.316579712223497, 3.430556115802072, 10.447804360416722, 10.111041902212126, 2.3394635990508434, 14.200464776578556, 5.450801921496368, 43.15283987203787]
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que la respuesta que pones como ejemplo es lo que esperas para la primera lista de distancias.

Tomando como base la lógica que planteas en tu solución podrías plantearlo así:

```
def IDW(estaciones, distancias):
    out = []
    for i in distancias:
        o = []
        for estacion in estaciones:
            suma_superior = 0
            suma_inferior = 0
            for j, k in enumerate(i):
                suma_superior += estacion[j] / i[j] ** 2
                suma_inferior += 1 / i[j] ** 2
            o.append(suma_superior / suma_inferior)
        out.append(o)
    return out


out = IDW(Est, Dist)
```

Lo que debes tener en cuenta es que en el bucle en el que iteras sobre cada elemento de distancia debes emparejarlo con cada elemento de estaciones para poder hacer la operación, es decir:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30370.8 | 33815.2 | 46185.7 | 19320.8 | 15449.4 |
| 5.5 | 5 | 4 | 23.6 | 0 |

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30370.8 | 33815.2 | 46185.7 | 19320.8 | 15449.4 |
| 1.2 | 0 | 2.4 | 20.2 | 0 |

...

Esto lo puedes conseguir con `enumerate()` que te devuelve el índice del elemento (en mi código sería `j`) y así puedes acceder a la estación correspondiente con `estacion[j]`

El resultado, con tus datos, sería el siguiente:

|  | Estación 1 | Estación 2 | Estación 3 | Estación 4 | Estación 5 | Estación 6 | Estación 7 | Estación 8 | Estación 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dist 1 | 8.11443 | 6.08208 | 2.20524 | 8.30947 | 8.33615 | 2.34781 | 14.2436 | 6.84283 | 41.9113 |
| Dist 2 | 2.65019 | 1.92481 | 0.685541 | 7.05527 | 4.5757 | 2.88431 | 10.9856 | 10.1417 | 46.9238 |
| Dist 3 | 2.90378 | 2.10697 | 0.750098 | 7.07323 | 4.76627 | 2.85267 | 11.1496 | 9.96078 | 46.5441 |
| Dist 4 | 5.12443 | 3.72239 | 1.32659 | 7.31224 | 6.36426 | 2.58584 | 12.492 | 8.46649 | 43.6492 |
| Dist 5 | 11.7357 | 9.31658 | 3.43056 | 10.4478 | 10.111 | 2.33946 | 14.2005 | 5.4508 | 43.1528 |

---

**List comprehension**

Esa misma función puede declararse así:

```
def IDW(e, d):
    return [[sum([_[j] / i[j] ** 2 for j, k in enumerate(i)]) / sum([1 / j ** 2 for j in i]) for _ in e] for i in d]
```